# Overriding Symfony Form's Save Function

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have two issues, need some help with.

I have a table which is referenced by a foreign key to a second table:

```
member_child:
    _attributes: { phpName: MemberChild }
    id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true }
    member_id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true, foreignTable: member, foreignReference: id }
    child_id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', required: true, foreignTable: child, foreignReference: id }
```

and child:

```
child:
    _attributes: { phpName: Child }
    id: { type: INTEGER, size: '11', primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true, required: true, onDelete: cascade }
    username: { type: VARCHAR, size: '45', required: true, defaultValue: '' }
    display: { type: TINYINT, size: '1', required: true, defaultValue: '1' }
    ...etc
```

(obviously this is propel)

Now, when I want to create a child object, using a form, I need to do two things:

1. On submit, submit a member id
2. override the doSave function so when the child is created, I can also create the member_child object

How can I accomplish these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, you can use embedForm like pankar said. Also you can override save method of your forms like this:

```
$this->childForm = new ChildForm();
$this->childMemberForm = new ChildMemberForm();

//binding, checking if form was sent etc.

if ($this->childForm->isValid() && $this->childMemberForm->isValid())
{
  //save method should return saved object
  $childObject = $this->childForm->save(); 
  //therefore this id could be used by next object
  $this->childMemberForm->save(childObject->getId()); 
}
```

I hope that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the built-in Symfony feature `sfForm::embedForm` in your parent form in order to save the child one, but I haven't figure out a a way of properly get this working.

One post I came across some time ago actually did provide me with the solution. [Have a look](http://www.blogs.uni-osnabrueck.de/rotapken/2009/03/13/symfony-merge-embedded-form/) and see if it fits your needs. Of course it's in Doctrine but I suppose it can be easily ported in Propel